# How do I install Gyachi on PPC Ubuntu?

Tags: skype, macosx

So I'm trying to install Gyachi on my iMac G5 runnig Ubuntu 12.04.1 but I can't seem to find a package that works on powerpc interface. I did find some powerpc enterprise Linux.rpm builds on the internet but I have no idea how to install them. This is the lin: http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/5/ppc/gyachi-1.1.71-5.el5.ppc.html

Does anyone know how to install that, or would it work?

Is there any Skype alternative that has both audio and video for Ubuntu? In my knowledge, Gyachi is the only one that at least does both audio and video for Yahoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I realized that there is no build of Gyachi for my system configuration... Pity...

Answer (score 1):

Add this ppa to your repository:
    ppa:adilson/experimental

Details: Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adilson/experimental
```

Next run a `sudo apt-get update` to refresh your list of repositories

Now install:

```
sudo apt-get install gyachi gyachi-plugins-extra
```

Enjoy, and thank Mr. Adilson dos Santos Dantas

From:
https://launchpad.net/~adilson/+archive/experimental